# Comparing IBM MQ to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq

I found several comparisons between Kafka and IBM MQ. But I didn't get all my answers yet. I have some conclusions and I need to confirm them. I know that IBM supports peer to peer. But, I'm comparing the Publisher\Subscriber modes and let's say the same cluster size. I'm mainly about concerned how Kafka compares to IBM MQ in the following area:

- Scalability: Both scale horizontally. However, Kafka is more
  scalable especially when it comes to number of consumers since it's using one log for all consumers.
- Robustness: IBM MQ is more robust. Kafka is not stable at times and
  act clumsy. This is somehow surprised me.
- Throughput: Kafka has much more throughput. Although, IBM MQ has
  throughput which enough for the vast majority of applications.
- Latency: I found contradictory opinions. Some people says kafka has
  less latency, while others says it has more.
- Availability: Both are very available.
- Fault tolerance: Both are fault tolerant. But Kafka wins here.
- Message persistence: Both persist messages. But kafka has better message persistent and it comes out of the box.
- Message replay: Both support message replay. I'm not sure which one is easier or better.
- Message ordering: Kafka only support ordering on partition level. IBM MQ supports on topic. Ordering can be done in kafka on topic level using keys.
- Security: Both support security. But IBM MQ has better security
  features. Learning curve for devs and ops: Kafka has more training
  materials and less complected to learn for both devs and ops.
- Other: IBM MQ as a standard messaging queue is more feature rich than
  Kafka. IBM MQ also support JMS which makes it more standard than
  Kafka. On the other hand, Kafka fits better in big data
  architectures, like Lambda. Also Kafka supports stream processing and
  has connectors too.

### Conclusion

Kafka is preferred for applications which need crazy throughput or that requires integration in big data stack and where losing few messages is not a big deal. On the other hand, IBM MQ to be used in applications where robustness  and stability is the key factor and that doesn't tolerate losing any messages.

### Note:

Those are just my findings. They can be right or wrong. Please correct the wrong ones and add the missing points.

Comment: "Message replay: Both support message replay. I'm not sure which one is easier or better." where did you read this about IBM MQ?   IBM  MQ does not store published messages other than a special case of a retained publication where IBM MQ stores the most recent pub for future subscribers.  Only current subscribers receive all published messages and once consumed by the subscriber there is no replay option.

Comment: "Kafka is not stable at times and act clumsy"—what's your source for this?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt You can read under cons section: https://www.waytoeasylearn.com/2018/11/apache-kafka-pros-and-cons.html. This is not the only, I fond while browsing on internet that some people complains about its stability. This surprised me as I said since I know it's used for some critical applications so I wanted to confirm

Comment: @JoshMc I learnt this from Kakfa and asked one IBM MQ user and he explain that it does. thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to reduce a comparison of MQ and Kafka to a few bullet points. From my point of view, each has use cases which suit it particularly well. They both scale, but in different ways. They're both secure, but in different ways. They're both highly available, but in different ways. MQ doesn't do message replay. Kafka doesn't participate in global transactions.

I would start with the use case and then see how well the characteristics of MQ and Kafka fit.

Comment: I totaly agree that we need to start with the use case. I tried to be general in my points as much as I can. But my specific use case, is that messaging in publisher\subscriber mode. Messages expected to be in millions daily by several publishers and several consumer groups will consume from multi topics, process message and insert into db. Consumers and producers expected to be in tens, not more than that. So I know that Kafka and IBM MQ can both cover this with ease. But I needed to know which one would have edge and preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Key differentiator would be streams. Just for pub sub architecture both are pretty much same except the old message messages are not retained for new consumers in case of IBM MQ .